# No DNS resolution if custom configured DNS server is not reachable - how to fallback to default DNS

Tags: macos, dns

How can I configure the DNS server in the network preferences with 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) for my Mac but have it default to local network DNS servers in case Google's DNS server is not reachable from a LAN?

Comment: It **is** possible to set up something you are asking for - but it is remote because it requires you to configure different locations, some bash scripts, maintain a database with all the networks you are using and a launch agent. DNS servers properly configured shouldn't require this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go to the terminal to find out what's your current DNSs using the command:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver
```

Then,

in your network settings, under "Advanced"

[image]

enter:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
x.x.x.x //local DNS
x.x.x.x //local DNS
```

If Google DNS won't work it will fallback to google other DNS server. If that fails too the fallback will be your local DNSs.

Comment: But there is no way to automatically fall back to *any* local DNS server if google DNS is unreachable?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Once some DNS is configured, the OS will only search for configured DNSs as fallback.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I only care about one particular local DNS, so I put that first. On any other network it will fall back to Google, which is fine by me.